# Why are red indicators showing on all my circuit breakers?

Tags: electrical, water-heater

[image: Model Number][image: Breakers showing Red "tripped" buuttons]As far as I can tell, all the breakers in my apartment's panel are showing as tripped (red 'button' visible), and yet everything has power... except my water heater. It is no longer heating up when I turn on the hot faucet. I tried the reset procedure described on the panel and all the red tags are still there. If these are all tripped, how is there still power to everything, and why isn't the hot water resetting?

I do not know if it's Tank or Tankless. It's an apartment, and the added pics are the breakers in my unit. It is Electric water heater.

All the breakers show that Red Button, but everything has power. The electric water heater however is the only thing not working.

At the base of the panel are these instructions for Resetting:

Locate breaker with Red Button.
Turn to Off Position.
Turn On.

It appears to be a Wadsworth panel.

Comment: "Tripped" usually means the failure state, power turned off. Are you sure that's the word you wanted to use?

Comment: A picture of the breakers will help.  Any chance of they being GFCI breakers and the red button is test/reset?

Comment: Some older QO will show a bit of red even when they aren't tripped. A picture or at least a model/type would help significantly. Also: breakers can fail.

Comment: A lot of stuff will stop working/break without tripping the breaker.

Comment: What make/model/type (tank vs. tankless, gas vs. electric) of hot water heater?

Comment: Google Image Search indicates this is a Wadsworth panel (via this Reddit link: https://www.reddit.com/r/electricians/comments/c4qmf0/does_anyone_know_what_type_of_breaker_i_should/ and further googling). It's very old, the breakers may not be made anymore. This source https://harrison-electric.com/Blog/entryid/245/3-types-of-electrical-service-panels-that-must-be-upgraded says the panel should be replaced.

Comment: Possible duplicate or at least parallel https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/139267/what-is-the-red-button-on-my-circuit-breaker